# Gulp 4 - Tasks not finished - Gulpfile.js Browsersync

Tags: node.js, sass, gulp, browser-sync

I'm a bit stuck with changing my old Gulp 3 Gulpfile to work in Gulp 4.

I have got to a point where it all seems to work except that the default and serve tasks are not marked as finished in powershell.

How can I unblock the code and allow them to finish correctly please?

```js
var gulp        = require('gulp');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
var sass        = require('gulp-sass');

// Compile sass into CSS & auto-inject into browsers
gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src(['node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss', 'src/scss/*.scss'])
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest("src/css"))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});

// Move the javascript files into our /src/js folder
gulp.task('js', function() {
    return gulp.src(['node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js', 'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js', 'node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js'])
        .pipe(gulp.dest("src/js"))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});

// Static Server + watching scss/html files
gulp.task('serve', gulp.series('sass', function() {

    browserSync.init({
        server: "./src"  
    });

    gulp.watch(['node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss', 'src/scss/*.scss'], gulp.series('sass'));
    gulp.watch("src/*.html").on('change', browserSync.reload);
}));

gulp.task('default', gulp.parallel('js', 'serve'));
```

Comment: I think you are good, you want the watches (within the serve task) to continue running.  And so the serve task never finishes and thus the default doesn't finish either.

Comment: See the official recipes for gulp4 at https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/4.0/docs/recipes/server-with-livereload-and-css-injection.md
They don't use a dummy callback function in their serve task with a sass watcher.  I don't think you gain anything here by using it.  This can be seen by changing your default task to gulp.series('serve', 'js') with no difference in operation.

Comment: Thank you Mark, I'll use the callback for now and will study the recipes to further develop my gulpfile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second task in your `serve` series doesn't return anything, gulp doesn't understand that. A task can return a stream or a promise - or it must call the callback parameter to signal completion, like so:

```
gulp.task('serve', gulp.series('sass', function(cb) {
    // Your js task code here
    cb()
}))
```

Read the latest [gulp4 documentation](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/tree/master/docs/api), it'll help you.

Comment: Thank you Kamil, this has allowed the tasks to finish and continue to watch and serve the site.